# Java - Split List<String> into... sublist?

Tags: java, string, list, split

I'm really not sure how to best ask this, so hopefully someone can figure out what I'm talking about.

Assume a List that looks something like this:

```
[
    "Harum beatae autem occaecati. Incidunt quis",
    "eius perferendis itaque dolorum dolores doloribus.",
    "Veniam voluptate mollitia\net aut qui magnam. Ut",
    "quos unde nulla qui. Earum odit dolores non illo illum."
]
```

I want to split it at the "\n" like so :

```
[
    "Harum beatae autem occaecati. Incidunt quis",
    "eius perferendis itaque dolorum dolores doloribus.",
    "Veniam voluptate mollitia",
    "et aut qui magnam. Ut",
    "quos unde nulla qui. Earum odit dolores non illo illum."
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I cannot differ between input and output.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza One of the strings has been split. The output list has five strings instead of four.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, there is _just_ one...

Comment: Input is four lines with a "\n" halfway through the third, output is five lines split at the newline

Comment: There may be multiple, or no, newlines in any given line. Additionally, list won't always be the same size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use stream and `flatMap` like this :

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If not you can use a simple loop like so :

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list){
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split("\n")));
}
```

Comment: I am actually using Java 8, the first option throws this error:

    Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)

Comment: Second option seems to work (but throws a security warning) but crashes on run

Comment: Small Correction : 
s.split("\n") should be s.split("\\n")

Comment: @DanGriffiths this is not possible check the [demo of java 8 solution](https://ideone.com/slJfgR) and a [demo of simple loop](https://ideone.com/Aq0L35)

Comment: @PraveenShendge no check the demos in my previous comment, it not cause any problem

Comment: @YCF_L I can assure you, that's a copy from Eclipse... it's the exact error it threw. Also, I'm running Java 8u181

Comment: @YCF_L, Sub-question: Am I right if I understood your first solution as 1) `list.stream()` produces a stream of `String`; 2) `flatMap` produces a `String` after `String` (called `s`) **and** splitting them into new `String[]`; 3) `collect` of course collecting the `String[]` into the `List`?

Comment: @zlakad flatMap return a stream of strings not an array of strings then the collect will convert that to a list of strings. sorry I use my phone for that I cant gives more details, I will exlain more when I back home

Comment: @YCF_L Ok, update. I was wrong, the code is valid. I was importing Arrays from Scala instead of Java for some stupid reason. That said... it doesn't work. It returns the same string, completely ignoring the "\n"

Comment: @DanGriffiths I don't get you in the last part? * it doesn't work. It returns the same string, completely ignoring the "\n" –* does my answer not show the correct results?

Comment: @DanGriffiths also can you try this `s.split("\\\\n")` instead of `s.split("\n")`

Comment: I found the problem! For whatever reason, my system is screwing up when I use "\n", I changed it to "%n" on a whim, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @zlakad I read before a nice book I would suggest to read it It explain how flatMap and every this how its work with an intelligent way the book is [Java 8 Lambdas](https://www.amazon.com/Java-Lambdas-Functional-Programming-Masses/dp/1449370772) hope this can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 public List<String> extractNewLineSeparatedStrings(String input) {

      List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();        
      if (input != null) {
        // split by new line
        String[] arr = input.split("\\n");
        result =  Arrays.asList(arr);
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: You're expecting a string input, I'm starting with a List

Answer (score 0):

Adding another way(simple) to achieve, using StringTokenizer

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list){
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,"\n");  
   while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   result.add(st.nextToken());
}
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, the code as provided does nothing. If I use \\n instead of \n, it breaks at every instance of 'n'... with or without the slash

Comment: Just did a test, changed it to match "%n" and it split at every instance of "n" as well. Oops?

Comment: pls send your correct input. i tried my answer in IDE and it is working fine

Comment: Right now my input is this: 

List<String> unformattedText = fontRenderer.listFormattedStringToWidth(inputText, maxWidth - 10);

Where inputText is:

inputText<String> = "Harum beatae\n autem occaecati."

Comment: let me see how you tried in your coding. cause this would surely work